# Sphinx SetSelect sortmode issue

Tags: php, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

i have been trying to sort alias field defined in the setselect method as below, but it is returning irrelevant records,

SetSelect sphinx query in Nested IF Condition

```
$sphinxObj->SetSelect("*, IF(CityId>2 AND CityId<10,1,IF(CityId>12 AND CityId<20,2,IF(CityId>22 AND CityId<30,3,IF(CityId>33 AND CityId<40,4,0)))) as Rank");
```

Below are Rank values, that cannot able to sort field(ASC or DESC).

```
Rank: 4
Rank: 4
Rank: 4
Rank: 2
Rank: 4
Rank: 2
Rank: 10
Rank: 5
Rank: 2
Rank: 2
Rank: 3
Rank: 1
Rank: 4
Rank: 4
Rank: 3
Rank: 2
Rank: 10
Rank: 10
Rank: 10
Rank: 10
```

I tried for the `$sphinxObj->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_ATTR_ASC, "Rank");` but it is throwing irrelevant records. Please any suggestion on this and how do i sort values that defined in SetSelect alias field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the `Rank` is not a defined attribute, so you can't use `SPH_SORT_ATTR_ASC`.

You want to sort based on an expressions, use [`SPH_SORT_EXPR` instead](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/sorting-modes.html#sort-expr).

Comment: Okay. But Using SPH_SORT_EXPR, Can we sort ASC or DESC values?

Comment: @Yadheendran: That and whatever you want. It's your expression, you formulate it, you're in control. ASC or DESC values it just a matter of viewpoint, e.g. either 1 to 10 or -10 to -1, e.g. multiply it with -1 if you need it ascending.

Answer (score 0):

'rank' is an internal alais of @weight.

I suggest using a differnt name for your new attribute.

should also be setting $sphinxObj->setRankingMode(SPH_RANK_NONE); to disable the internal ranking.